# How to get record's "Ref" in FaunaDB predicate function?

Tags: abac, faunadb

I am trying to prepare “write” predicate function. The idea is to allow user changing only his own profile. I am comparing the “id” from Token and record “Ref”.
By the logic it should work like this:

```
  q.Lambda(
    ['old', 'new'],
    q.Equals(
      q.Select(["id"], q.CurrentIdentity()),
      q.Select(['ref'], q.Var('old'))
    )
  )
)
```

But it doesn’t: **“Error: Insufficient privileges to perform the action.”**
By the “predicate function” documentation:

> *write, history_write: the **old data, the new data, and a reference** to the document to be written.*

I changed the function, but the error still appears. The code:

```
q.Query(
  q.Lambda(
    ['old', 'new', 'ref'],
    q.Equals(
      q.Select(["id"], q.CurrentIdentity()),
      q.Var('ref')
    )
  )
)
```

I also tried to hardcode the user ID to this function and it works well:

```
q.Query(
  q.Lambda(
    ['old', 'new', 'ref'],
    q.Equals(
      q.Select(["id"], q.CurrentIdentity()),
      "295870713291604487"    
    )
  )
)
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
q.Query(
  q.Lambda(
    ['old', 'new', 'ref'],
    q.Equals(
      q.CurrentIdentity(),
      q.Var('ref')
    )
  )
)
```

Similar to this: https://github.com/Vadorequest/rwa-faunadb-reaflow-nextjs-magic/blob/main/fauna/roles/Editor.ts#L73-L81

The `q.Var('ref')` returns a `Ref` object, not an `id`.